# dynamically create azure webjobs from list

Tags: azure-webjobs

I a server that has webjobs that get some data from a local sites.
the number of the local sites can be changed and my question is, is there any way to create a webjobs according to list of sites?
I must add that the webjob should be continuous.

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit more what you try to achieve ? what I understand is that you want to depoy a webjob as per web site deployment ?

Comment: Ok i will try to explain. I have a web site with webjobs. those webjob get some data from local apps that run on different locations.Each local site has his own webjob. Now,Lets say that i want to add a new local site so instead of writing a new webjob i just want to insert it to a list and let the code generate  the webjob (after uploading the website again). Hope it is more clear now.

Comment: Do you mean each local site will generate a azure webjob? The webjob codes is the same? It doesn't need change any codes in the webjob?

Comment: The webjobs are the same the only different is the app.config (some differences in connection strings) my plan that if you take the website down and bring it up again it will generate the webjobs from from db (the code is the same + but the differences at the app config it will take from the db). i must add that I don't think it can be done but i thought maybe some one has an idea.

Comment: @roybarak Any update? If you feel my answer is useful /helpful.Please mark it as an answer so that other folks could benefit from it.

Comment: @BrandoZhang it is look like a good answer but i didn't got the chance to examine it yet, but i didn't abounded the issue so somewhere in the nearest future i will be back to it.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I suggest you could write codes to deploy your web jobs according to the web app's name(You could write a loop to deploy the webjob with the web app).

In webjob function, you could write codes to ask the connection string from sql db or azure storage according to the current web app's name.(You could use Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_SITE_NAME") to get the current web app name).

About how to deploy the webjob by codes, you could refer to below codes.

Notice: Firstly you should create a web job project in Visual studio. Then you should package the bin's debug folder as a zip file. We will upload this zip file to the azure web app.

Steps about how to upload the zip file to web app.

1.Set the deployment credentials.

[image]

2.Replace the web site name and user name and password with the deployment credentials.

```
    public static void WebApiSample()
    {
        string siteName = "yourwebsitename";
        String username = "username";
        String password = "password";
        String encoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(
        System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(username + ":" + password));

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri($"https://{siteName}.scm.azurewebsites.net/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Basic {encoded}");  
        deployJobAsync(client,$"myJob-2", @"path\Debug.zip").Wait();

    }

    private static async Task deployJobAsync(HttpClient client,string jobName, string zipFileName)
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(zipFileName))
        {

            StreamContent streamContent = new StreamContent(reader.BaseStream);
            var response = await
            client.PutAsync($"api/zip/site/wwwroot/App_Data/jobs/continuous/{jobName}/",
            streamContent);
            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                return;
            else
                throw new Exception(result);
        }
    }
```

Result:

[image]